# React-modal-sheet doesn't block background and you can manipulate rest of page when bottom-sheet is open

Tags: popup, overlay, modal-sheet

The problem is that sheet overlay doesn't block background and when manipulating page several sheets can be opened at one time. It's necessary that you can open only one sheet at once. Sheet.Backdrop didn't solve the item.

Using react-aria/overlays didn't help.
Did anybody meet such a problem and what is it solution?